# Expression Lambda with types known at runtime

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I am trying to make some Expressions where I will be using a lambda to create two methods: a selector and condition. Simplified the usage is `condition(selector(data))`, but the intemediate type is only known at runtime. I have the following code which works as long as the intemediate type is object, but at runtime I know the real type and would like to use that.

```
    public static ICondition<TData> GetRelayConditionByReflection(string name, string message, string assemblyName,
        string fullyQualifiedName, string conditionMethodName, string selectorMethodName) {
        var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
        var type = asm.GetType(fullyQualifiedName);
        var selectorMi = type.GetMethod(selectorMethodName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var conditionMi = type.GetMethod(conditionMethodName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        var tCondType = selectorMi.ReturnType;
        var returnType = typeof(RelayCondition<,>);
        var typeArgs = new[] { typeof(TData), tCondType };



        var paramTData = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TData), "data");
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TData, object>>(
            Expression.Call(selectorMi, paramTData), paramTData).Compile();

        var paramTCondition = Expression.Parameter(tCondType, "condition");

        var condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(
            Expression.Call(conditionMi, paramTCondition), paramTCondition).Compile();



        return (ICondition<TData>)Activator.CreateInstance(returnType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs), name, condition, message, selector);
    }
```

Specifically, there is `Expression.Lambda<Func<TData, object>>` and `Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>` where `object` currently only allows the intemediate type to be object.

Is it possible to create this with a type known only at runtime? I am open for other approaches for the entire problem, as long as performance isn't attrocius.

Comment: Why do you care what the intermediate type is?

Comment: I don't, but if I use object, I both methods must use object in their definition, and I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need implicit downcasting (for example declaring a `Func<object>` when in truth you method returns a `Func<Foo>`), you can use the non-generic `Expression.Lambda()` method. It returns a `LambdaExpression`, but in truth it returns a `Expression<>` of `Func<>` or of `Action` downcasted to `LambdaExpression` (`Expression<>` is a subclass of `LambdaExpression`), so:

```
var condition = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Call(conditionMi, paramTCondition), paramTCondition).Compile();
```

now `condition` is a `Delegate`, but in truth it is a `Func<>` (or an `Action` if it had a return type `void`).

Comment: That works, and it figures out at runtime that the delegate is of the appropiate type and throws an exception if not. Types are conserved and still failing fast in case of an error. Thank.